# Where can I find the full list of steps required to sell a house without an agent in a given US state?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

In a recent question [Why is it uncommon to sell houses without an agent in the US?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129716/why-is-it-uncommon-to-sell-houses-without-an-agent-in-the-us) I received the following reply:

> There are several complex details and activity sequences that you need
> to know about, and most people buy real estate rather rarely, so they
> might not know them, or not remember them. In addition, compared to
> other typical transactions, every error can bear significant losses;
> buying a rotted or moldy house can easily set you back five or ten
> annual salaries.

Where can I find the list of "complex details" and "activity sequences" for a given US state? In my last real estate transactions the agents have netted more than $40k and I'd be more than happy to do all the work myself when I sell the house, even if it costs me an entire month of effort.

Comment: 40k$ a month sounds like a salary equivalent I'd take too. Looking forward to some good answers! I'm afraid that anyone starting such a website would get strong pushback from realtor associations, arguing that only 'certified qualified agents' are allowed to help in the process... after all, a well-built overview could ruin a whole (money-printing) industry.

Comment: Don't expect to save the full commission amount. If the buyer doesn't have the comfort of a realtor, they will want to split the savings with you.

Comment: @Mattman944 I'd be much more happy to give a 3% discount to a buyer than throw away 6% for something I can do myself perfectly well. I absolutely despise transaction fees of any kind.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer you quoted is a bit off base.

Beyond surface appearance, a realtor isn't going to know if a home is rotted or moldy.  That's the reason that a buyer gets a home inspection.  If there are problems, the seller can either offer a selling concession or make any  repairs that impede  closing the deal.

Draw up a contract with the counter party and use a real estate lawyer to review it so that you are protected.

Use a title company to handle the closing.  They will know and either manage or instruct you on how to handle the "complex details and activity sequences that you need to know about."

I've bought and sold several homes myself at a cost of less than 1%.  The only effort I had to make was working out the contract with the counter party.  The lawyer and the title company handled the rest.

Disclaimer: Laws vary from state to state so I don't guarantee that this option is available to you.